# Не могу подключить Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Создал новый проект.
Подключил **Hibernate** и **PostgreSQL**.

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Создал **persistence.xml** в resources/META-INF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
             version="2.2">

    <persistence-unit name="demo">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.example.demo.Account</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value="debt"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value="debt"/>

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.highlight_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Создал POJO класс

```
package com.example.demo;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import static jakarta.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNTS")
public final class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ACC_ID")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "ACC_LOGIN")
    private String login;
    @Column(name = "ACC_ISDISABLED")
    private Boolean blocked;
    @Column(name = "ACC_NOTE")
    private String note;
    
    public Account() {
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Account{" +
               "login='" + login + '\'' +
               ", blocked=" + blocked +
               ", note='" + note + '\'' +
               '}';
    }
}
```

Написал тестовый запрос

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf =
                Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("demo");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            Account account = em.find(Account.class, 1L);
            System.out.println(account);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            em.close();
            emf.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Но вместо данных получил ошибку:

```
янв. 30, 2023 12:44:03 AM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: demo]
янв. 30, 2023 12:44:03 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.6.Final
янв. 30, 2023 12:44:04 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using built-in connection pool (not intended for production use)
янв. 30, 2023 12:44:04 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: Loaded JDBC driver class: org.postgresql.Driver
янв. 30, 2023 12:44:04 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001012: Connecting with JDBC URL [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test]
янв. 30, 2023 12:44:04 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=debt}
янв. 30, 2023 12:44:04 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
янв. 30, 2023 12:44:04 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH10001115: Connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
янв. 30, 2023 12:44:06 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl logSelectedDialect
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
янв. 30, 2023 12:44:07 AM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@422b8438] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
янв. 30, 2023 12:44:07 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42703
янв. 30, 2023 12:44:07 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Колонки start_value не найдено в этом ResultSet’’е.
янв. 30, 2023 12:44:07 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PoolState stop
INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test]
янв. 30, 2023 12:44:07 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections close
ERROR: Connection leak detected: there are 1 unclosed connections upon shutting down pool jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
янв. 30, 2023 12:44:07 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl validateConnectionsReturned
ERROR: Connection leak detected: there are 1 unclosed connections
Exception in thread "main" jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: demo] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1509)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1430)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:55)
    at jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:80)
    at jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at com.example.demo.Main.main(Main.java:10)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unable to build DatabaseInformation
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:143)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:415)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1425)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Колонки start_value не найдено в этом ResultSet’’е.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.findColumn(PgResultSet.java:2939)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getLong(PgResultSet.java:2822)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.resultSetStartValueSize(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.lambda$extractMetadata$0(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.spi.ExtractionContext.getQueryResults(ExtractionContext.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.<init>(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:176)
    ... 12 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Вроде же всё делал по [Getting Started Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/quickstart/html_single/) и [User Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#bootstrap-jpa-compliant).

Comment: в каком из созданных `entities` есть поле `start_value` ? Судя по стеку - у вас валится на создании EntityManagerFactory, видимо - на сканированировании пакета

Comment: Я показал весь код, в этом и проблема, что я понятия не имею о каком `start_value` оно говорит.

Comment: Тогда проверьте импорты. Тот ли Account Вы маппите?

Answer (score 1):

В моём случае проблема была в

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
```

Убрал его, и код заработал. Похоже в таблице есть какие-то проблемы.